# Google Actions sdk not playing audio using ssml

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es, ssml

I have tried to play small size audio using SSML, but the below code throws the error **" expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt.items[0].simple_response: 'display_text' must be set or 'ssml' must have a valid display rendering. "**

```
// See https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
// for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');


const {
  MediaObject
 } = require('actions-on-google');

const LOGO_IMG = 'https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX/skill/Logo1200.jpg'

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
     agent.add(new Card({
         title: `TITLE`,
         imageUrl: LOGO_IMG,
         text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `
       })
   );

    const welcomeText = 'Welcome message';
    agent.add(welcomeText);
  }

  function playsong(agent) {
    agent.add('<speak> <audio  src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/alarm_clock.ogg"></audio></speak>');
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('PlaySongIntents', playsong);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message mentions, if you're sending SSML, you either need to have some part of the SSML be able to be displayed on non-audio devices, or you need to provide a separate text message for it to display.

In this case, you can change your `playsong()` function to something like

```
  function playsong(agent) {
    agent.add('<speak> <audio  src="https://actions.google.com/sounds/v1/alarms/alarm_clock.ogg">Alarm!</audio></speak>');
  }
```